# The meaning of "over" here?

Tags: prepositions, difference

He stayed married over a quarter of a century.

This "over" has two possibilities?
a time span..like "over many years"

and "over" means more than?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's right.  *Over* can have either meaning:

1. He stayed married **more than** a quarter of a century.
2. He stayed married **for** a quarter of a century.

Context could make one meaning or the other obvious, but in this case we have no context so all we can say is that it's ambiguous.